# Unknown character in SSH terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh

Does anyone know what causes the `â` character to show up on this statement. The file name does not contain that character preceeding This is just an example of an `rm` command, it happens in other commands as well.

```
rm  JOB0013_RRDS_HOLC_RUN_SEG_HIST1.log
```

returns

```
remove regular file âJOB0013_RRDS_HOLC_RUN_SEG_HIST1.logâ
```

The command correctly executes, it's just annoying.  I'm using Tectia SSH on Linux

Comment: Probably a misconfiguration in the client's character set translation (e.g. ISO-8859 versus UTF-8)